# ArcGIS / BING map overlay on Google map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, arcgis

I was searching the net few days and can't find any answer - it is possible to add ArcGIS (esri maps) and/or BING map as overlay on Google maps app on android? I founded that it is possible to do this in web version but no information about android. So, it is possible in some way or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [BingMapsLayer class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/android-sdk/api/reference/com/esri/android/map/bing/BingMapsLayer.html).

```
MapView mv = new MapView(this);
mv.addLayer(new BingMapsLayer("[your Bing Maps key]", MapStyle.Aerial));
setContentView(mv);
```

Comment: But does it work on Google Maps API? I want to add layer on app with Google Maps API, not on ArcGIS.